# How to check if x86 assembler AT&T code is ok?

Tags: testing, assembly, x86, compiler-construction, att

I'm writing a small C compiler using SLY (python) and x86 AT&T syntax. I want to check if the code I'm generating is ok, because I don't know so much about this assembler language.
Some years ago I did something similar with MIPS32 and I used MARS to check if the code was correct.

Is there anything that I can use to check the code? Also, if you know any similar project it would be very useful.

Comment: You can check if the syntax is valid by assembling it with `as` / `gas` (the GNU assembler).  To actually make sure you used the right instructions, you'd need to run or simulate the resulting code and check the results.  And/or write unit-tests for your compiler to make sure given small inputs compile to an expected sequence of instructions.  (e.g. LLVM has test inputs as part of the source tree, updated along with commits.  At least for SIMD vectorization.  Useful to see which commits improve or regress asm output if you're looking by hand.)

Comment: There is AFAIK no general way to be sure your compiler has no wrong-code bugs.  Otherwise GCC and other compilers would probably already be doing that, and wrong-code bugs wouldn't exist (which is unfortunately not the case).  So probably your best bet is just to compile stuff and test it, and compare the results to programs produced by other compilers.  A UB-free program should generally give the same results on two different implementations that agree on type widths and so on.

Comment: csmith might be a useful tool here.

Comment: find & run some C compiler tests.